What is the best way to approach this?
I run into very specific tasks, so I decided to join the forums )
I am relatively new to blender and am trying to learn the best ways.
I am modeling a temple that looks like this:

I noticed it has a bisymmetry, so I'll just model half of it and mirror it. But the front wall has a lot of detail that I need to replicate. So, I could subdivide it using edge loops and extract the formed "pixels"

Or do I use the knife tool to create the vertices and edges and then extrude it?
So what I am asking what are the best methods pertaining to modeling real estate with detail?

unfortunately these kind of questions are problematic on this site, because they might be getting closed because it's opinion based. This site has some strict rules so i recommend asking "how can i" so you don't risk that your question will be closed.

I agree with Chris. Any suggestions would be opinion-based as everyone has different ideas. Voted to close.

Just to elaborate on why this is opinion-based, this amount of quads is definitely not suitable for say a mobile video game. But if you're going to model a temple that will appear in the foreground of the next Avengers movie you will need a LOT more detail. Please add  bit more background to your specific workflow and needs. As a rule of thumb if you're beginning you should aim for the least amount of geometry to achieve your goal. You can always subdivide a mesh, un-subdividing after the fact is way harder.

Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

While it's true that the modeling style depend a lot on what you want it for, here's a few pointers:

You don't need the hole object to be full of small quads. That kind of geometry is usually reserved for things that are going to deform. It's not needed in a building.

Things usually don't need to be a single object/mesh. Instead of extruding all the detail manually from the faces you can use other objects. You can use a boolean modifier to cut windows out of the wall with one or more box type objects. Depending on the use of the model you may need to apply the modifier and clean the topology, but that's still a lot easier than covering it in quads.

You can make the details on the top by modeling one of them and giving it an array modifier

The crenelations don't need to be connected to the main wall either, as they need a lot more geometry and will be hard to connect. The objects just need to overlap to look good.


There's a lot of youtube tutorials on how to model architectural stuff so look them up if you are just starting.

